# RxSwift Canceling RxMoya networking request

Tags: swift, networking, request, rx-swift, moya

I'm using MoyaRx networking for the search field and would like to cancel the request when the field is empty.

```
let response = request
    .flatMapLatest {
        provider.rx.request($0)
        .map(T.self)
        .asDriver(onErrorRecover: { error in
            return Driver.just(.error(error))
        })
    }
```

But Moya manuals don't have code for my purpose. Can you suggest something?

Answer (score 0):

The below is what you are looking for:

```
let response = request
    .flatMapLatest {
        $0.isEmpty ? Driver.empty() :
        provider.rx.request($0)
            .map(T.self)
            .asDriver(onErrorRecover: { error in
                return Driver.just(.error(error))
            })
}
```

Note that I added one line. I'm assuming that `$0` is of type String.

If the string is empty, instead of making a request, the flatMapLatest will cancel any ongoing requests and emit a `completed` event. This will *not* complete the chain, because `request` also has to complete before the chain completes, but it will setup the flatMapLatest to accept another event.